# Stop flash slides on mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

**EDIT:**

I'm creating a flash banner where I have several objects that come and go. In the end of my banner a contact form appears. I need the animation to stop when the users clicks on any of the input fields. How do I achieve this in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your input fields add the following:

```
_inputField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK clickHandler);
```

Then add the following function:

```
public function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
stop();
}
```

The 'stop' assumes you're using the timeline as your animation. If the animation is contained in a MovieClip do something like the following:

```
_containingMovieClip.stop();
```

Comment: Do I need to add the `public function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
stop();
}` as a button that covers the whole banner as if I'm adding a clickTag?

Comment: If you're using just the timeline, add the function code (and .addEventListeners) to a frame in the time line (You can press F9 to open the actionscript panel). If you're using external classes, the code will need to go where the input fields are instantiated; somewhere where you have access to the references to the input fields.

Comment: Right now I'm getting several errors. Syntax related errors: `1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before clickHandler.` and `The public attribute can only be used inside a package.`

Comment: Are you using external Classes? If so, the clickHandler function needs to be OUTSIDE the constructor function of whatever Class you're adding it to. The first error is telling you to put a right paren '}' before the clickHandler function (at the end of the previous function). The second error is happening because Flash expects the public function to be declared outside of a function.

Comment: `inputs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 trace("Mouse clicked");

 stop();
}` solved the problem. Thanks moosefetcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a mousover listener pointed to the banner

```
banner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverNow)

banner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseNotOverNow)

function mouseOverNow(e){
    stopSlide = true;
}
function mouseNotOverNow(e){
    stopSlide = false;
}
```

and you will have to make a check in your animation whether `stopSlide` is true or false before continuing to a new slide.

something like

```
if(!stopSlide){
    banner.play();
}
```